# group_send() in Django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

When ever a channel is created I'm adding it in a group. The issue is server sends the message to the latest channel in the group only rather than broadcasting it to the whole group. If I've two channels in my group the message will be sent to the latest in the group, twice.
Help me debug.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer,AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from .models import Chat, Room
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync,sync_to_async


class MyAsyncWebsocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print('connected...')
        self.group_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['group_name']
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

        # Get old chats from database
        chat = await sync_to_async(Chat.objects.get)(room = await sync_to_async(Room.objects.get)(room_name = self.group_name))

        await self.accept()

        # Show old chats 
        await self.send(text_data=chat.chat)

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        print('disconnected....')
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        print('Server sending messages...')

        # if user is authenticated save chat in database
        if self.scope['user'].is_authenticated:
            print('User is authenticated')

            prev_chat =  await sync_to_async(Chat.objects.get)(room = await sync_to_async(Room.objects.get)(room_name = self.group_name))
            new_chat =  prev_chat.chat + '\n' + text_data
            prev_chat.chat = new_chat
            await sync_to_async(prev_chat.save)()
            # Saved 

            # Broadcasts
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.group_name,
                {
                    "type": "chat.message",
                    "message": text_data,
                }
            )
        else:
            print('User is not authenticated')

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # Send a message down to the client
        print('Sending actual message...',event["message"])
        await self.send(event["message"])
        # print(self.channel_name)
```